# Google Chrome Monospace Fonts Hard to Read

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, chrome

In Google Chrome on Ubuntu, I find it hard to read code.  How can I change the font settings to make it easier to read?

Comment: This question is really unclear. Read code in what exactly? Also in instances like this some form of image to demonstrate exactly what you mean would add a great deal of clarity to the question. Also, are we talking about Google Chrome, or a font which is named Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, web browser like to make the monospace font smaller than other text, which can make `code` harder to read.  There are two ways to handle this in Chrome.

### Option 1: Customize Font Settings

Click the wrench icon.

Select "Preferences"

Select "Under the Hood"

Under "Web Content" you can "Customize Fonts..." -- you'll want to change the "**Fixed-width font**."

### Option 2: Font Zoom

While viewing a web page, hold the `control` key and hit `-` or `+` to decrease or increase the font size.  Your "zoom" setting will be used for all pages on that web site.

You can check on and change the Zoom setting for the page you are viewing by clicking the wrench icon.

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu 11.04, using the Chrome browser I found some of the monospaced fonts very hard to read, especially code from github.com.  What made a "night and day" difference for me was the following:

Install the **The Bitstream Vera family of free TrueType fonts**.

- Open the **Software Center**.
- Select **Fonts**, on the right (under **Departments**).
- Find or search for "vera"
- Install.
- Restart Chrome.